# Caption an equation paragraph

Tags: latex

I am trying to include different equation paragraphs in my LaTex document. Is it somehow possible to visually separate the paragraphs (e.g. by horizontal lines) and give them different captions?
I don't want the captions to emerge in the table of content, just underneath the equations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\begin{document}

\section{Mathematical Formulation}

\begin{equation}
    \operatorname{Max} F=\sum_{u,v  \in V  \mid u<v} \left(d_{uv} + d_{vu}\right) x_{uv}
\end{equation}
such that: 
\begin{equation} 
\sum_{l \in L_{u v}} y_{l} \geq x_{u v} \hspace{4em} u, v \in V \mid u<v
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \sum_{l \in \tilde L_{i j}} y_{l} \geq 1 \hspace{5em} \ \lbrack i,j \rbrack \in E
\end{equation}


%Next paragraph here 

\begin{equation}
\operatorname{Min} F=\sum_{u \in V} \sum_{l \in L} \sum_{(i, j) \in \vec {E_{l}}} t_{l i j} x_{u l i j}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\sum_{l \in L} \sum_{(i, v) \in \vec{E}_{l}} x_{u l i v}-\sum_{l \in L} \sum_{(v, j) \in \vec{E}_{l}} x_{u l v j}=d_{u v} \hspace{4em} u,v \in V \mid u \ne v
\end{equation}



\end{document}
```

The caption should look similar to the one for my GAMS code:

[image]

Comment: You can add horizontal lines with `\noindent\hrulefill`. Can you make a sketch how the caption should look like?

Comment: Thanks, the horizontal lines work! I included an examplary picture to my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a custom command like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcounter{foo}

\newcommand{\mycaption}[1]{
{
  \medskip
  \centering
  \setcounter{foo}{\theequation}
  \addtocounter{foo}{1}
  Equation \thefoo: #1
  
  \vskip-0.5\baselineskip
  \noindent\hrulefill
}
}

\begin{document}

\section{Mathematical Formulation}

\begin{equation}
    \operatorname{Max} F=\sum_{u,v  \in V  \mid u<v} \left(d_{uv} + d_{vu}\right) x_{uv}
\end{equation}
such that: 
\begin{equation} 
\sum_{l \in L_{u v}} y_{l} \geq x_{u v} \hspace{4em} u, v \in V \mid u<v
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \sum_{l \in \tilde L_{i j}} y_{l} \geq 1 \hspace{5em} \ \lbrack i,j \rbrack \in E
\end{equation}


%Next paragraph here 


\mycaption{some text}
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{Min} F=\sum_{u \in V} \sum_{l \in L} \sum_{(i, j) \in \vec {E_{l}}} t_{l i j} x_{u l i j}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\sum_{l \in L} \sum_{(i, v) \in \vec{E}_{l}} x_{u l i v}-\sum_{l \in L} \sum_{(v, j) \in \vec{E}_{l}} x_{u l v j}=d_{u v} \hspace{4em} u,v \in V \mid u \ne v
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Or if you prefer a separate counter:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcounter{foo}

\newcommand{\mycaption}[1]{
{
  \medskip
  \centering
%  \setcounter{foo}{\theequation}
  \addtocounter{foo}{1}
  Model \thefoo: #1
  
  \vskip-0.5\baselineskip
  \noindent\hrulefill
}
}

\begin{document}

\section{Mathematical Formulation}

\begin{equation}
    \operatorname{Max} F=\sum_{u,v  \in V  \mid u<v} \left(d_{uv} + d_{vu}\right) x_{uv}
\end{equation}
such that: 
\begin{equation} 
\sum_{l \in L_{u v}} y_{l} \geq x_{u v} \hspace{4em} u, v \in V \mid u<v
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \sum_{l \in \tilde L_{i j}} y_{l} \geq 1 \hspace{5em} \ \lbrack i,j \rbrack \in E
\end{equation}


%Next paragraph here 


\mycaption{some text}
\begin{equation*}
\operatorname{Min} F=\sum_{u \in V} \sum_{l \in L} \sum_{(i, j) \in \vec {E_{l}}} t_{l i j} x_{u l i j}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation}
\sum_{l \in L} \sum_{(i, v) \in \vec{E}_{l}} x_{u l i v}-\sum_{l \in L} \sum_{(v, j) \in \vec{E}_{l}} x_{u l v j}=d_{u v} \hspace{4em} u,v \in V \mid u \ne v
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to change the caption number manually? Because I would like to start with "Model 1", not "Equation 4".

Comment: @Laura I added a version with a separate counter